# Where is total_forks from forks.c initialized?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

Hi I am trying to create a counter that will just count the number of times the system call vfork() has been called in fork.c in the Linux kernel source. I'am following how total_forks is implemented. Total_forks is defined in sched.h. But I can't find where it is initialized to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are talking about the Linux kernel, and the variable *declared* in `sched.h` and *defined* [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.37/kernel/fork.c#L82). It's a global variable (defined at file scope and not `static`) - these are implicitly initialized to zero. Try this in you own code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    printf( "var is %d\n", var );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the source you're looking at, but a few thoughts spring to mind:

It may be initialized to 1 when `init` is started.

It may be initialized to 0 because it is in the [BSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) segment; the runtime system knows to initialize a portion of memory for variables and clears it all before giving it to the 'main' kernel process at early boot.